# Swift: UISegmentedControl last index is not selected

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have to select `UISegmentedControl` index programmatically on `viewWillAppear()`.

```
switch shirtSize {
    case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.xs.rawValue:
        shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.s.rawValue:
        shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
    case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.m.rawValue:
        shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2
    case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.l.rawValue:
        shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 3
    case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.xl.rawValue:
        shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 4
    default:
        break
}
```

When the last index (4) is selected, the corresponding segment is not graphically selected. When I manually tap on the last segment, it becomes selected but the `valueChange` callback is not called. This means that the the `selectedSegmentIndex` was already set and it's just a graphic bug. What can I do? For all the other values (0-3) it perfectly works.

Comment: Can you check the value of `momentary` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618586-momentary when wanting to switch to the last index?

Comment: What happens if you call `shirtSizeSegmentedControl.setNeedsDisplay()` after the `switch`?

Comment: @denis_lor the value is false

Comment: @vacawama nothing happens, I don't know why this regards only the last index. If I add a dummy segment at the end, it works for index 4

Comment: Try moving the code into viewDidAppear. Does that fix it?  Just as an experiment.

Comment: @matt I already tried it, but It didn't work. Using setNeedsLayout() did, but honestly I can't understand why it was just about the last segment.

Comment: @Heisenberg I re-edited my question, can you please take a look and try if that works as well? Would you also leave a comment instead of just downvoting? I'm trying to figure out what could be possible solutions that could work in other circumstances as well...

Comment: @denis_lor I didn't downvote your answer, I hadn't even seen it because SO hid it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to refresh the layout:

```
setNeedsLayout();
```

Comment: With setNeedsLayout() it works. I don't know what to say, It makes no sense...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    perform(#selector(switchShirtSizeSegment(shirtSize:)), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.0)
}

@objc func switchShirtSizeSegment(shirtSize: Int) {
    switch shirtSize {
        case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.xs.rawValue:
            shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.s.rawValue:
            shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.m.rawValue:
            shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2
        case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.l.rawValue:
            shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 3
        case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.xl.rawValue:
            shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 4
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I don't think it's a problem of timing because it works for all the other segments

Comment: I thought it was a matter of running it again after the first run loop, so to redraw itself again. But eventually it might depend on some circumstances that are unknown with the information we have. Thanks for trying out!

Answer (score 0):

Use momentary property of UISegmentControl.

Try following -

```
    switch shirtSize {
      case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.xs.rawValue:
           shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
      case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.s.rawValue:
           shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
      case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.m.rawValue:
           shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2
      case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.l.rawValue:
           shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 3
      case ProfilingPreferredShirtSize.xl.rawValue:
           shirtSizeSegmentedControl.momentary = true
           shirtSizeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 4
           shirtSizeSegmentedControl.momentary = false
      default:
           break
}
```